# What is the ipmitool "Auth Type"?

Tags: ipmi, ipmitool

What's the meaning of `Auth Type Support: NONE MD2 MD5 PASSWORD` and `Auth Type Enable : Callback : MD2 MD5 PASSWORD`?

When I use `lan print 1` in my server, `ipmitool` shows the following output:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ipmitool -I open lan print 1
Set in Progress         : Set Complete
Auth Type Support       : NONE MD2 MD5 PASSWORD 
Auth Type Enable        : Callback : MD2 MD5 PASSWORD 
                        : User     : MD2 MD5 PASSWORD 
                        : Operator : MD2 MD5 PASSWORD 
                        : Admin    : MD2 MD5 PASSWORD 
                        : OEM      : MD2 MD5 PASSWORD 
IP Address Source       : Static Address
IP Address              : 172.16.22.237
Subnet Mask             : 255.255.255.0
MAC Address             : 00:25:90:a9:42:4a
SNMP Community String   : public
IP Header               : TTL=0x00 Flags=0x00 Precedence=0x00 TOS=0x00
BMC ARP Control         : ARP Responses Enabled, Gratuitous ARP Disabled
Default Gateway IP      : 0.0.0.0
Default Gateway MAC     : 00:00:00:00:00:00
Backup Gateway IP       : 0.0.0.0
Backup Gateway MAC      : 00:00:00:00:00:00
802.1q VLAN ID          : Disabled
802.1q VLAN Priority    : 0
RMCP+ Cipher Suites     : 1,2,3,6,7,8,11,12
Cipher Suite Priv Max   : aaaaXXaaaXXaaXX
                        :     X=Cipher Suite Unused
                        :     c=CALLBACK
                        :     u=USER
                        :     o=OPERATOR
                        :     a=ADMIN
                        :     O=OEM
Bad Password Threshold  : Not Available
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like most tools, `ipmitool` comes with a man page [`man ipmitool`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ipmitool). The application's online manual will usually either explain outricht or more often than not *hint at* what the output means.

Often a bit of background knowledge helps for context though.

> **`-A <authtype>`**
>   Specify an authentication type to use during IPMIv1.5 lan session activation. Supported types are NONE, PASSWORD, MD2, MD5, or OEM.

In other words:

The [IPMI protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface) allows different mechanisms to authenticate. Your IPMI device does not need to support all of them to be standards compliant, so ipmitool will display which ones YOUR device does support:

```
Auth Type Support   :  NONE MD2 MD5 PASSWORD
```

So your device supports all authentication types, *except* `OEM`.

```
Auth Type Enable        : Callback : MD2 MD5 PASSWORD 
                        : User     : MD2 MD5 PASSWORD 
                        : Operator : MD2 MD5 PASSWORD 
                        : Admin    : MD2 MD5 PASSWORD 
                        : OEM      : MD2 MD5 PASSWORD
```

That is a list of which authentication mechanisms are supported for each (default) ipmi user account. As you can see `NONE` is absent there, in other words, you will always need a valid password to log in to and use any of those accounts.

You can supply the password in plain text: the `PASSWORD` mechanism,
or use a (cryptographic weak) [`MD2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD2_(hash_function)) message digest,
or use a (cryptographically stronger) [`MD5`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) message digest to authenticate
.